# Filter by custom field in custom post type

Tags: wordpress

how to add custom filter in custom post type by wordpress custom field

Answer (score 2):

The advanced custom fields plugin has a very good documentation at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com. Query by custom fields is explained [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/).

In a nutshell:

For custom fields, you can use `meta_key` and `meta_value`.

```php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_key'      => 'color',
    'meta_value'    => 'red'
));
```

If you want to order by a custom field, say a date field called `start_date`, specify `'orderby'='meta_value'` in `get_posts` and specify the type of the key, here `'meta_type'='DATETIME'` (see [here for more info](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/)):

```php
// query events order
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'          => 'start_date',
    'meta_type'         => 'DATETIME'
));
```

Comment: thanks sir but i want to add a dropdown  to select color on top post page

Comment: your question and comments are not clear. You have a custom field 'color' and want to let the user filter posts based on the color ?

Comment: yes my custom field is color and i want to user can filter post to selecting value from dropdown list

Comment: So you need to write a dropdown and use the code above to filter your posts. Browse the custom field documentation for examples and tips.

Comment: Can you Please help me to do this

Comment: how can i do that